# Proper type for underlying std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, c++11, std

I'm pretty new to C++, so I apologize if the answer to this is obvious.

I've been writing an STL-style custom data structure as a way to improve my skills. (I actually do have a practical need for this structure as well, but I'm going a little overboard for study purposes.)

This structure needs to dynamically resize (like a vector), and in my first draft, I made the underlying "container" a C-style array and did all the allocations and de-allocations manually. I'm refactoring, and I'd like to use a C++11-style std::array as my underlying structure, just to make the code a little cleaner. My problem is that I don't know how to declare the array class member in a way that allows for resizing. Since different template parameters entail a different type, I can't just declare a member as array and then assign the same variable to an array upon resize.

I thought about declaring a member for each potential size, like

```
private:
    array<T, 8>
    array<T, 16>
    array<T, 32>
    ...
```

but I don't want each of those arrays default constructing T members.

Is there a clean solution here? Or do I just have to stick with C-style arrays?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

After re-reading my question, I don't think it makes sense, actually. I understood that std::array's size had to be known at compile time, but for some reason my brain to infer that my goal was impossible. It seems obvious to me now that I'm stuck with C-style arrays and the heap. I think I just needed to write it out to get perfectly clear.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If your structure is like a vector and needs dynamic resizing, why don't you use a vector as the underlying structure and add the additional functionality that you need on top of it? An `std::array` is meant to provide a container whose size is known *at compile time*, it doesn't provide a good foundation for a vector implementation.

Comment: Just stick with dynamic, manually managed arrays.  They need to be dealt with at some level, and that level is `std::vector`.  If you're re-implementing `std::vector`, then you have to deal with them yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::array` represents an array whose size is known statically (i.e. at compile time), so it cannot be used in cases such as this where the size will be only known at runtime.

Simply use `std::vector` instead, it has a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that takes the size as its argument.

Comment: I know it will be met with doubt, but there is actually good reason to squeeze a lot of performance out of this structure. I've already written it with a C-style array underlying, so if I can't use std::array, I'll just leave it as is.

Comment: @piyo: And is your structure more performant than `std::vector`?  If so, you should share it.

Comment: @piyo: Well, `vector` certainly cannot be *faster* than an array but I think you will be hard-pressed to measure any performance difference.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It's not a vector implementation. It's a specialized deque variant.

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` is specifically designed not to be resizable.  It's mainly a workaround for the fact that fixed-size arrays aren't first-class value types.

Comment: Right. I get that. But C-style arrays aren't meant to be resizable either, and yet it still makes sense to use them as the underlying type for a container, no?

Comment: @piyo if you're using `new[]` then that isn't using C-style arrays, although the syntax is similar.

Comment: @piyo: No, very much not so. In fact, you should *never* use dynamic C-style arrays in C++ at all (i.e. `new[]`). It's much better to separate memory and object lifetime (e.g. using an allocator), like `std::vector` does it. Since your data structure already needs to store the size of the container, there's no point having the raw array also track that information separately.

Comment: @KerrekSB Got it. In my current implementation, I did use the Allocator (no calls to new).

Answer (score 1):

The only use case that I can think of is some sort of externalized or serialized object (stored on disk or delivered over socket, or something along those lines), where there is a dynamically sized component. If you already have a format defined for that, then you should probably stick with what you have. Trying to reuse `std::array<>` for this will not work if the sizes are not known at compile time.

If you want to refactor, what might be useful would be a template class that can take a C array as a constructor argument, but provide an STL container interface to it.